# how do I set up a setTimeout without using a callback by the useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

so as part of learning react I am currently converting a class-based App to a functional one, I've encountered some issues with my code since I can't use the callback function in the following context:

```
  class ColorBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { copied: false };
    this.changeCopyState = this.changeCopyState.bind(this);
  }
  changeCopyState() {
    this.setState({ copied: true }, () => {
      **setTimeout(() => this.setState({ copied: false }), 1500);**
    });
  }
```

I've tried to change it using the useEffect hook, to the following:

```
function ColorBox(props) {
const [isCopied, setIsCopied] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => setTimeout(() => setIsCopied(false), 1500), [isCopied])


const changeCopyState = () => {
    setIsCopied(true)
};
```

but the problem is that the useEffect renders at the first render which makes the app glitch if I don't wait for 1500ms before clicking on the copy button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

effects will fire whenever the values of your dependencies change. However, what you want according to your class-based approach is to, after setting `isCopied` to `true`, set it to `false` after 1500 ms.

To do so, check the current value of `isCopied` in your effect before firing the timeout.

```
function ColorBox(props) {
  const [isCopied, setIsCopied] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isCopied) {
      setTimeout(() => setIsCopied(false), 1500)
    }
  }, [isCopied, setIsCopied])

  const changeCopyState = () => {
      setIsCopied(true)
  };
}
```

In addition to that, for consistency, you might want to use `clearTimeout` when unmounting your effect (in order to avoid, for instance, calling `setIsCopied` after the component has unmounted).

To do so, the effect has to be like this

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (isCopied) {
          let timeoutId = setTimeout(() => setIsCopied(false), 1500)
          return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
        }
      }, [isCopied, setIsCopied])
```

Comment: I've tried this approach before but for some reason, the console gave an error, I guess I didn't use the curly braces correctly.
Anyway your solution works, So Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

When you don't specify a curly braces `{}` in arrow function, it will return a value. 
 In `useEffect` you don't need a value to be returned (the only exception is `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method). That drove to unpredictable behavior and timeout was fired at the initial render. 
 Use curly braces `{}` in your `useEffect` arrow function instead

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => setIsCopied(false),1500)
    }, [isCopied]);
```